# How to go from Sandbox mode to Production - Woocommerce paypal powered by Braintree

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment-gateway, braintree-sandbox

I've made sure that everything works with the Sandbox Mode offered by Braintree, I now want to go to transition to production mode and allow real payment transaction.

In order to do this, I must put in the merchant ID and API keys for the production mode

From reading the instructions offered from Braintree's official site [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/go-live/php), I need to enter in this code

```
require_once(plugins_url() . '/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/braintree_sdk/lib/Braintree.php');
Braintree_Configuration::environment('production');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('YOUR_PRODUCTION_MERCHANT_ID');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('YOUR_PRODUCTION_PUBLIC_KEY');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('YOUR_PRODUCTION_PRIVATE_KEY');
```

NOTE: this code here is not in the official braintree instructions but it has been recommended by other sites to use this in order to fix the issue:
      require_once(plugins_url() . '/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/braintree_sdk/lib/Braintree.php');

however, when I do, it gives me the following error:
"Fatal error: Class 'Braintree_Configuration' not found in /home4/fierytycoon/public_html/resumego.net/wp-content/themes/divi-childtheme/functions.php on line 136"

Line 136 refers to the first line of the code used           "Braintree_Configuration::environment('production');"

how do I fix this error and get myself from sandbox testing mode to production live mode?

Comment: I would think the Braintree plugin has an admin option to toggle between sandbox and live modes. Is that not the case?

Comment: no unfortunately not, ive called braintree up and they said to use the merchantid and public/private keys provided and that these are seperate from the sandbox account

Comment: Looking at their screenshots [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/screenshots/) I'd guess that you have to disconnect from your Sandbox account and then reconnect to your merchant account. I still don't think you should have to add code, but this plugin doesn't have very high ratings so who knows.

Comment: i've disconnected from my Sandbox acc already, but can't find a place to enter the key/merchant ID i need to, but yea the low ratings from the plugin is concerning

Comment: Look at the screenshots I linked, the first shot looks like a big button that says "Connect with Braintree". I'd guess that's it, as the description says you don't have to paste in any API keys, but again I don't use this myself and am just guessing based on the docu.

Comment: the problem i run into when i click that button is that it asks me to recreate my account and asks for my full social security number, I already created an account from the braintree site that only requires my last 4 digits, so I am trying to avoid this inefficient method...perhaps I should look for alternatives to this plugin but it seems there are not many others

Comment: I downloaded it and when I click on that button see: "WooCommerce would like you to use Braintree to accept payments online. Start by creating a new account or logging in with an existing one." Have you tried logging it with existing credentials? Here's an [alternative](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-braintree-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: yes, when i log in with my existing credentials, it still asks me for info like name/last name/email/address and more importantly, a full social security number which i dont want to put in when i already put in last 4 digits to create the original acc....i will try the alternative u provided as well as another im looking at which seems promising...thanks for your insight

Comment: Good luck. Guess this explains why it has such a poor rating.